# How to cythonize global __builtin__ objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, cythonize

I have a problem "cythonizing" a project written in python.
1. A python class (declared in file **myclass.py**) is instantiated, then "declared global" using setattr(__builtin__...) in file **main.py**
2. A function declared in a module (file **module.py**) access this class instance by its global name ("globalclass"), and set some values.

So the question is: How to cythonize a python module referring an object instance by its "global name" definned outside of the module with setattr(__builtin__...) ?

I run python 2.7.15 on windows x86, with Cython 0.29.1.
The code provided below works fine when I run pure python:

```sh
python main.py
```

But cythonizing the file **module.py** gives me an error: **undeclared name not builtin** referring the global name of the class instance "globalclass".

Here is the file **myclass.pyx**, the definition of the class:

```py
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = ''

    def setValue(self,text):
        self.value = text

    def printValue(self):
        print self.value
```

Here is the file **module.pyx**: this is the file I want to cythonize, but cython says **undeclared name not builtin** "globalclass":

```py
def setValue():
    globalclass.setValue('test from module.py')
```

Here is the file **main.py** (entry point) where the class is instantiated, and "declared global" using setattr(__builtin__...):

```py
import __builtin__
from myclass import Myclass
from module import setValue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myclass = Myclass()
    setattr(__builtin__, 'globalclass', myclass)
    setValue()
    globalclass.printValue()
```

And here is the file **setup.py** used to cythonize the all:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

cyextensions = [
    Extension(name='myclass', sources=['myclass.pyx']),
    Extension(name='module', sources=['module.pyx']),
    ]

setup(name='test',
      version = '0.0.1',
      description = 'test',
      packages = ['test'],
      ext_modules = cythonize(cyextensions)
)
```

And here is the command I use to cythonize:

```sh
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Here is the error message I get when cythonizing:

```sh
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
def setValue():
        globalclass.setValue('test from module.py')^
------------------------------------------------------------

module.pyx:2:1: undeclared name not builtin: globalclass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an a place where Cython differs from Python (although it isn't documented hugely well). Essentially it assumes that it should be able to resolve all global names at compile-time, while what you're doing affects it at runtime.

[Fortunately there's an option to turn this behaviour off](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#Cython.Compiler.Options.error_on_unknown_names). Simply add two lines to setup.py (as shown in the documentation above)

```
from Cython.Compiler import Options
Options.error_on_unknown_names = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The cython compiler gets the information about python builtins at runtime.
So **modifying 'builtins' before / while compiling** will solve the problem without taking further action. 
  *I.e. use sitecustomize, usercustomize or some 'yourname'.pth to 
    'import my_builtin_patching_module' for the compile step.
  Make sure the import will take your original .py, not the compiled one, 
  otherwise the imported .pyd/.so may be locked, preventing the compiler output.*